# iPad - UINavigationBar exceeds width, ViewController as half screen subview

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I'm adding a ViewController as a subview to my main view, like so:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Backstage" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BackstageHomeViewController"];
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
```

The problem is, that the UINavigationBar still has the original full screen width and appears cut off at the edge.

[image]

How can I change the width to match the view that it is contained in?

Comment: Are you opening a new story board or working with the one the app started with?

Comment: A new storyboard. I use that as an "area" where all viewcontrollers will be displayed in the subview, that only takes up the left half of the screen.

Comment: Haven't tried it but is it not possible to modify the initial view controllers frame (Freeform setting)?

Comment: Yes, freeform. I think it's only the background that is not being adjusted. As you can see from the screenshot the title is centered, so the UINavigationBar does have the correct size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay -- iOS 6 just solved this issue with the new Container View, that allows you to embed a `UIViewController` inside a `UIView`. Resizes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);`

Comment: I'm trying to make it take up only half of the screen, which works fine. The problem is, that the UINavigationBar's background is being cut off, but I think I need a custom background...

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me to expand the width of a view to the width of its parent view controller.